# What is the difference between fighting and combat?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there a reason to keep two seperate tags for [fighting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fighting) and [combat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combat)? Or should we consolidate?

Answer (score 5):

consolidate the tags, there is no difference.

Comment: I think that one of the moderators should setup a synonym for combat <- fighting.

Comment: I have done this.

Comment: @Eric Weilnau @mxyzplk - Should that really be a synonym? My first instinct when I heard there was a "fighting" tag was that it was about players fighting amongst each other IRL. Is there anyone else who had that reaction?

Comment: @LeguRi That was not how the tags were actually being used. Even if it was, i think that the "fighting" tag would be vague in that context.